# Capture letters in field containing letters+numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to clean some data in my database.

I have a column that contains both letters and numbers.

I would like to build a query that will catch all the field for which there is more than 4 letters in a row.

```
1293.8093CHINA34324            -- (YES)
MY32498VN34983-294TH32498PH    -- (NO)
WORLD_3244932                  -- (YES)
9HEY850249.243943              -- (NO)
32484359-78049                 -- (NO)
3294832.49234PROGRAMMATION     -- (YES)
```

Thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) to the rescue

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]{4}'
```

My Original query said [A-Z] Tim, kindly edited and added a case insensitive regex. The original regex was based on the assumption that your mysql database has a case insensitive collation (which is the default)

Comment: thanks @tim-biegeleisen for the edit, the bit about case insensitivity now become obsolete :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a query for sql server:-
select name from (select * from [tests].[dbo].[emplo]
   where len(name)>=4) as s where name like '%[a-z][A-Z]%'